# How to know source location of file been copied

Tags: ftp

We have dedicated server at Rackspace.com. And website is running fine too. But, issue is that a file is been automatically getting replaced in this website from somewhere. And this source location has old version of this page.

Is there a way we could identify from what location/server the file is coming. I know the approx time when it get replaced. I have already verified the Syncovery tool that we are using at our other servers to send data to this server.

Let me know, if any other detail is required.

FYI: Scenario is much more complicated actually, but defined here very generally.

FYI: this is not because of some coding, but syncing. I am sure of it.

Comment: "Scenario is much more complicated actually, but defined here very generally." Given that your issue is likely to be due to your complicated setup, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: You tagged your question FTP?  Is that the method you are using to upload files?  Or are you using sftp, or what? (you really shouldn't use plain old ftp)  My suggestion would be to setup verbose monitoring for whatever service you are using for remote access.  The other thing you might consider is setting up incrond to monitor the file changes, and trigger a script to capture the netstat/who output maybe.  You could also look at setting up a watch with auditd, that should give you lots of details.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Yea, I understand. But, what I am trying to get is if its that simple than how one could find the source location. Can a tool like fiddler be of any help.

Comment: @iMatoria are you permitting uploading via webdav?  If not, then an http debug proxy like fiddler isn't going to help you much.

Comment: @Zoredache: Could you please provide some links for "incrond to monitor file changes" and "watch with auditd". Thanks.

Comment: @Zoredache: I don't know what webdav is. But, we upload via Filezilla ftp client.

Comment: I added a comment, and not an answer because I don't have time to write out a full tutorial right now.  You can certainly go search Google and this site incrond, auditd, webdav, and so on.  You should be able to find lots of hints, guides and so with a little homework on your part.

Comment: @Zoredache: Thanks. I thought you might be owner of these tools, so I asked it. Yea, I had already started with search.